# Add feature no longer working

Tags: qgis, vector, editing, features

I'm using QGIS 2.16 but this was happening on 2.14 as well and I hoped updating would fix it but no.

I create a new shapefile, doesn't matter whether it's a point, line or polygon, toggle edit function, and then use the edit add feature function to add a feature to the new shapefile. When right-clicking to finish my new feature the feature attributes window pops up but it is blank and I can't edit the attribute which means I can't add the feature. See the image.

I suspect there is a conflict with some other software on my computer or a previous version hasn't been removed completely because I have been having trouble with browsers and videos as well.  I have tried using the tools of CCleaner to tidy up my registry and redundant files.  I tried updating from 2.14 to 2.16 and I have tried removing 2.16 cleaning everything and reinstalling 2.16 but the problem still exists.  Can anybody offer some advice of what else to try?

[image: screenshot of blank feature attributes pop up]

Note the other edit tools work such as copy, paste, move and node tool and my work around is to copy and paste a feature then reshape with node tool or move it but this is slow.  None of the add... tools work.

Comment: in the table try adding a column (using the table editor) If you having issues projection might not be set when creating a shapefile. workaround get a shapefile (of the web) and delete all geometry and then create your own fields.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but none of that works.  I used to be able to add features to shapefiles and have tried existing and new shapefiles with project CRS matching shapefile CRS and have tried adding additional attribute fields,

Comment: Can you edit existing, older shapefiles?

Comment: No I can't add features to existing shapefiles.  I used to be able to but now I get the blank feature attribute window.

Comment: Try to uninstall your QGIS from your machine, install updates to your operating system and reinstall QGIS.